# [Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0) in Parse using Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I keep getting this error when trying to update a PFObject '[Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)' here is my code:

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")

    userQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("cE3DE48Fa9") {
        (userQueryObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else if let userQueryObject = userQueryObject {

            userQueryObject["House_Motto"] = self.campaignMottoTextBox.text

            userQueryObject.saveInBackground()


        }        }
```

What do I do?

Here is my new code:

```
currentUser!.setObject(self.campaignMottoTextBox.text!, forKey: "House_Motto")
```

Comment: When querying the User class in Parse you should use the specific user query, `let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!` . I can post an example if you would like, however my example uses `userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundwithBlock()` unlike yours where you are trying to get an object for a given ID

Comment: @MikeG can i see the example?

Comment: Well my example was on how to query the user class properly. But what you have said you want to do it to update a value in Parse correct? To update a value for a particular user you will use, for example: `currentUser.setObject(self.campaignMotto.text, forKey: "columnNameInParse") followed by `currentUser.saveInBackground` (or whichever save method you prefer).

Comment: It still didn't update the field

Comment: Please add the new code that you are trying to use so I may see what you could be doing wrong.

Comment: @MikeG I just updated my question

Comment: is `"House_Motto"` spelled EXACTLY the same here as it is in your Parse column? Capitalization and everything? including the underscore `_` between words? If it is then have you successfully updated anything to Parse yet? Such as a user? Did you go through the Parse quickstart guide where they walk you through creating/updating your first user object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103140/discussion-between-apple-geek-and-mikeg).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use `PFUser.query()` to query the user class in parse, note my example uses `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()`, rather than `getObjectsInBackgroundWithId()`

```
var userData1 = [String]()
var userData2 = [Double]()
var allUsers = [PFUser]()

func fetchUserData() {
    let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

    userQuery.orderByAscending("username")
    userQuery.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: (currentUser?.username)!)
    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (users, error) -> Void in

        var userData = users!

        if error == nil {
            if userData.count >= 1 {
                for i in 0...users!.count-1 {
                    self.userData1.append(userData[i].valueForKey("columnNameInParse1") as! String)
                    self.startTimes.append(userData[i].valueForKey("ColumnNameInParse2") as! Double)
                }
            }

            self.allUsers = users as! [PFUser]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

and in order to update a value for a given user you will do...

```
   func updateObjectInParse(){
    currentUser?.setObject(campaignMottoText.text, forKey: "columnNameInParse")
    currentUser?.saveInBackground()
}
```

where `"columnNameInParse"` is the name of the column for the object of which you want to update in parse. This is case sensitive. And currentUser is the `PFUser.currentUser`