# How to pull custom PFUser field from Parse into UILabel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I have an Xcode project where I am taking fields from a registration page and then pushing them to parse. I have another view where I have labels where I would to like to pull those custom fields from Parse into.

This is how I have stored the data:
        let myUser: PFUser = PFUser();

```
    myUser.username = userName
    myUser.password = userPassword
    myUser.email = userEmail
    myUser.setObject(userVehicle!, forKey: "User_Vehicle")
    myUser.setObject(userlicensePlate!, forKey: "User_Plate")
     myUser.setObject(userFirstName!, forKey: "First_Name")
```

Now I am looking to pull First_Name, User_Plate and User_Vehicle into UILabels in a view and cannot figure out how to do it. I have seen where people are querying the Parse database in their code but do not see how to then pull that into a label. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you got the current user? Have you logged the data available?

Comment: I answered a similar question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35280779/5544696) . From that you can see how to query the user class and get the data from a specified user at a specified column name. You will want to either set your text labels text property directly equal to the query results OR set a variable(x)  equal to the query results and then set your labels text property equal to that variable(x) elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

```
user["First_Name"] as! String
```

If you want to get current user from cloud or get list of users from cloud, you'd better check Parse.com guides. Link: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-querying

You can also set values like this:

```
user["First_Name"] = userVehicle!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have that user's information stored locally, you can access it like so:

```
    myUser.objectForKey(userVehicle!, forKey: "User_Vehicle") as? String
    myUser.objectForKey(userlicensePlate!, forKey: "User_Plate") as? String
    myUser.objectForKey(userFirstName!, forKey: "First_Name") as? String
```

Those methods will return the vehicle, plate, and first name respectively.

If you no longer have that object stored locally, you can query the Parse server:

```
    let query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("objectID", equalTo: YourUsersObjectID) //Or whatever field you want your query to be based on
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        //Your block here
    }
```

Then follow the methods above to access the fields you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am hitting an error when trying to access the User_Plate. It is saying there is an expected declaration. Will post code in following comment

Comment: let query = PFUser.currentUser()
    query.whereKey("User_Plate", equalTo:User_Plate)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    User_Plate = driverPlate
    }

Comment: driverPlate is my UILabel and User_Plate is my custom class within PFUser that I want to pull. So essentially I want to grab the currentUsers User_Plate which is a custom field i want to pull into a UILabel. Thanks in Advance

Comment: For one, you want query.whereKey("User_Plate", equalTo: _____)
Let the blank space there be the actual plate you're looking for. So if the plate had the value WMY68P, you'd want that in there as a string (or whatever type is stored in your database). That's also not the correct format for a block. Check out the docs, specifically the section on queries; that should clear some stuff up for you. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries